# Cannot start market activity with CLEAR_TOP flag

Tags: android

Consider this code snippet that prompts the user to rate the app on the market:

```
private void backToMainActivity() {
    Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mActivity.startActivity(i);

    mActivity.finish();
}

...

if (mRateToast.leftClicked(x, y)) {
    setRate(true);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + GameGlobals.PACKAGE_NAME));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mActivity.startActivity(i);

    backToMainActivity();
} else if (mRateToast.rightClicked(x, y)) {
    setRate(false);
    backToMainActivity();
}
```

What this does is detect what button was pressed (Rate or Later), set a flag accordingly and run the market app if needed. No matter which button is pressed, I want to return to the main menu (this is a game activity, 1 activity away from the main menu activity).

On Android 4.1, this works fine - the market opens to the app's page, and on return from the market, I am on the main menu. On android <= 2.3, the market does not open, I am just returned directly to the main menu. It does, however, open if I comment the `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` in the `backToMainActivity` method. This causes other problems though, such as the back button going back to the wrong activity instead of exiting the app, so is not a solution.

How can I run the market, return to main menu and have the main menu activity be at the top of the activity stack?

**Note:** I haven't tried it, but removing the `finish` is also not really an option. My game activity can also be started by external applications directly, and in that case, if I remove the `finish` call, for some reason `CLEAR_TOP` will not work, and pressing the back button on the main menu activity will return to the game activity instead of exiting the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and using `startActivityForResult` as described by [MoshErsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737925/moshersan) in his answer. Apparently starting the market as a new task does not play well with `CLEAR_TOP` in android <= 2.3.

If someone can explain why the original approach wasn't working or offer a better solution, I will accept that answer in one or two days, if not I will accept mine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + GameGlobals.PACKAGE_NAME));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mActivity.startActivityForResult(i,1552);
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==1552){
        backToMainActivity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same thing unfortunately: it gets back to the main menu, but the market does not open. I also get this warning in logcat on 2.1: `09-13 20:04:19.983: WARN/ActivityManager(2233): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{47eba9f0 my.app.package/.GameActivity}`

Comment: remove `mActivity.finish();` from `backToMainActivity();`

Comment: I explained at the end of my OP why I can't do that. It's not an option unless you can suggest an alternative to `CLEAR_TOP` when the game activity is directly started from an external app.

Comment: i didnt get your point, plz explain , btw read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: when you launch a new activity using  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP , it will close the whole actvities you lanched before, so when you click back , or finish it, the application will exit.

Comment: My app's game activity can open images from external programs. If I select to open an image with my app from the e-mail client for example, it opens fine. Then I finish the game involving that image, and call `backToMainActivity()` and I return to the main menu activity. Now, if I hit back or click the `exit` button (which calls  `finish()` on the main menu activity), I am returned to the game activity instead of exiting the app (this is if I remove the `mActivity.finish()`, if I don't it works fine). The problem only occurs if the game activity is started directly from another app.

Comment: So basically it looks like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` won't clear the root activity. This is a problem when the game activity is the root activity. If I have `Game -> Menu`, starting `Menu` with `CLEAR_TOP` won't clear `Game`, unless I call `finish()`. If I have `Menu -> Another -> Game`, starting `Menu` again will clear everything even without the `finish()`.

Comment: Sorry, what? I don't have a solution. It works just fine with the `finish()` on Android 4.1, only <= 2.3 seems to have a problem. That's why I posted the question :P.

Comment: Well, removing the `finish` call won't make the market open on `2.1` anyway, I just tested it. Only removing the `CLEAR_TOP` will.